# Loop child nodes inside parent in AngleSharp c# or vb

Tags: anglesharp

I am using AngleSharp to parse a html string.

I can get it to parse an out div that contains some inner divs / h3 tags i want to extract, but I can't work out how to do

I have so far

```
    Dim outer_linq = document.All.Where(Function(w) w.LocalName = "div" AndAlso w.ClassList.Contains("the-product"))
    For Each item In outer_linq

        If item.LocalName = "h1" AndAlso item.ClassList.Contains("the-product-title") Then
            ' Found h1.the-product-title, so do something with it here
        End If

        If item.LocalName = "div" AndAlso item.ClassList.Contains("price") Then
            ' Found div.price, so do something with it here
        End If

    Next
```

So it is finding everyting inside of div.the-product, but how do i look through div.the-product and get the h1.the-product-title and div.price for each set in div.the-product ?

There are several div.the-product and each one contains a h1.the-product-title and div.price

Using VB but c# would be ok too.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 3):

While you can leverage techniques such as LINQ in AngleSharp we encourage everyone to use the DOM (Document Object Model) as much as possible.

Instead of using `document.All.Where` you should just use `document.QuerySelectorAll`:

```cs
document.QuerySelectorAll("div.the-product")
```

You could even then perform the nesting directly, e.g.,

```cs
document.QuerySelectorAll("div.the-product h1.the-product-title")
```

would find all h1 elements having a `the-product-title` class and being *below* (descendants) of div elements having a `the-product` class. If you want to have children (instead of descendants) just use the `>` operator:

```cs
document.QuerySelectorAll("div.the-product > h1.the-product-title")
```

What your code above makes wrong is that you use `item` again. All retrieved items are actually already `div` elements (that's what you iterate over), so they cannot be `h1` elements, too.

An easy fix of your code above is that you use the outer loop as written above, but within you would write, e.g.,

```cs
Dim allInnerH1 = item.QuerySelectorAll("h1.the-product-title")
Dim allInnerPrices = item.QuerySelectorAll("div.price")
```